# Is it possible to submit an update for an app on the AppStore without losing reviews?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Whenever I submit an update for me app, the number of reviews visible for it drops to 0. If the customer bothers to click through they can see the previous versions' reviews...

But the damage has been done. Since the app has 0 stars, I see a significant drop in sales. It takes the app a good week of earning new reviews to restore sales.

I usually version the app as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.

Is there something I can do during the update process to prevent losing reviews like this?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, but one about the App Store and its submission processes, so Stack Overflow is not the appropriate place for this.  I would instead ask at Apple's Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: @Brad there's a precedent. Go look in the Related column.

Comment: There are inconsistencies due to differences of opinion about what's programming-related or not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/poll-which-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-appropriate .  I tend to believe that App Store questions are more appropriate on Apple's forums, and I think you'll get better responses there.

Comment: @Brad I'm glad that's what you tend to believe, the unicorns over in meta are entitled to their opinions. But have you ever spent time in the Apple forums? No thanks. I'd rather skirt with pseudo-moderators than deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

Nope you cannot do this. Users will always see the number of ratings for the current version and not the total for all versions.

Comment: Ugh, what a disincentive! Every time I update the app I lose sales? Geeze...

Comment: Want to know another bad thing? I am actually from Estonia, where "a very popular app" will have ~3 reviews in the AppStore, meaning I have no idea if an app is good or bad before I buy it. OK, I actually will go and look from US store, but you get the idea … But if people are interested enough they will check out the ratings for the previous versions :-) Atleast I do it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually losing reviews.  iTunes only shows reviews for the current version (when enough reviews are available).  On the app page the overall is still listed.  There is no way to override this behavior, so make your updates infrequent.

Comment: I understand the distinction thanks. **Effectively** I lose the reviews due to their poor UI.

Comment: But I am not sure if it would be in the users intrest to change the UI. When I buy an app I will always get the last version and I am actually very interested how that specific version works and would want to be blinded with thousands of reviews saying great app when the thruth is that the latest version has smaller functionality or worse performance. 

Same goes with devs. the review grouping by version game after developers wanted to get rid of bad reviews that came with problems in previous versions that have already been fixed in the newer ones.